# Why is my object invisible in blender cycles render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm using blender 2.82 and I've tried using every fix for invisible renders in cycles but I can't figure it out. It looks fine in Eevee but shows up transparent/invisible when I render in cycles. It seems to only happen with the dark bits of the object. The monster I'm showing here is entirely dark so its completely invisible.

[image]

Comment: can you share the blend file? https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: without seeing any of your settings of your object we can only guess around